# I need to use 0.6 volt signal to power a 12 volt solenoid

Tags: relay

I have a central locking control box which puts out 0.6 volts when pressing the trunk release button. This is obviously not enough to drive solenoid on the trunk to open it. What is the easiest way to use this low volt signal to open the trunk. Please bear in mind that the signal is temporary maybe only on for 2 seconds

Comment: What exactly provides that signal? How much current can it source? Did they seriously choose to provide 600 mV? Or is that just the base-emitter voltage of some random BJT in the circuit that is "being tapped" for this purpose? What else do you know about the details. Everything helps.

Comment: How can we tell if the control box is faulty or your measurement was not performed right or something else?

Comment: It's a printed circuit board. Not sure what puts the signal out. I have just emailed the supplier to check the voltage is correct. I measured it with my multimeter. I'll bring the work one home tomorrow and check again

Comment: If  a solenoid pullup was connected then the output is a low side switch with some rise of 0.6V that you may have measured due to current.  Was there a load?

Comment: What does it put out when NOT pressing the button? (As usual it's up to me to ask the dumb question.... sigh)

Comment: What about a single supply comparator to get the signal up to 5V ? Any 5V input solenoid driver would do the trick afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt your measurement is correct, and you are simply measuring an open-collector transistor that was intended to directly drive the solenoid.

If that is true you would measure 0V (due to the impedance of the multimeter to ground) and ~0.6V due to the forward-biasing of the base junction and the very low current circulating through the collector junction into your multimeter.

First, use the multimeter to measure from Vdd (not ground) and see if you get 12V when the circuit is activated. This will provide support for my suspicions.

The only doubt remaining is if the circuit can provide enough current to drive the solenoid. There is no good way to non-destructively check this, unless you can access the part numbers and values from the relevant section of the schematic.

But if it can’t, just by adding a resistor you would have a 12V pulse that would be much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assuming you're looking at a digital signal that can't supply much current.

The circuit will be fairly complicated unfortunately. Your going to need a comparator chip. Basically it has 2 inputs, and it turns on if input+ is higher than input-. You can set input- to 0.3v (with a voltage divider). And then the comparator will turn on when your 0.6v signal goes high. You should be able to get a 12v comparator and run it straight from your car 12v. (you'll probably want to put some caps on the 12v though to smooth it out).

Hook the output of this comparator to an N-Channel mosfset and use that to switch the solenoid. (google low side mosfet switch for schematics).

Make sure to put a flyback diode on the solenoid or it will blow out the mosfet immediately. Basically just get a diode and put it across the solenoid so that power doesn't flow through it in normal operation.

Comment: You could also use a cheap (dc) solid state relay from amazon instead of the mosfet. The flyback diode will still be necessary.

Comment: Why are you commenting on your own answer? Edit the answer instead.

Comment: Why would you use an op-amp? if you have a 12v power source when you just need a transistor.

Comment: @Vinzent The 0.6V signal would be barely enough to turn on the transistor, that's why he says to use an comparator. Even if you got 0.6V to turn on a bipolar transistor, it may not be reliable over temperature.